# Finding equation by given definitions.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> In each of the following if there exists a function $f$ that satisfies the given condition, give an example of such a function; otherwise just write DOES NOT EXIST inside the box. No explanation is required. No partial credit will be given.
>
> $\mathbf b.$ $f$ is differentiable on $(-\infty,\infty)$, $f$ has no zeros and $f'$ has at least two distinct zeros.
>   $$f(x)=\boxed{\color{blue}{\,\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+1}\,}$$

how it can be found and is there a specific way or mostly based on guessing ?

Comment: This is *one* function. There are many more. What about $y=1$?

Comment: it can be that either but how can this be found in a short time is there a any practical way

Comment: By understanding what is being asked, making a mental picture then using your knowledge of well-known functions.

Comment: may be y = 1 cannot be because it is indicated that two distinct zeros

Comment: It says "*at least* two distinct zeros".

Comment: @Pumpkin it says *at least* two distinct zeroes. Continuum-many clearly qualifies.

Comment: but the answer  isn't too complicated to guess such a function ?

Comment: Actually, I would have come up with something like $f(x)=\sin(x)+2$ (because I missed the obvious $f(x)=1$)

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen My first function was $5+\sin(kx)$ where $k>0$. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to construct a function with a certain number of zeroes is by considering polynomials.  A simple example of a polynomial with at least two distinct zeroes is:

$$
(x-1)x(x+1)=x^3-x
$$

The indefinite integral for this function is:

$$
x^4/4-x^2/2+c
$$

If we make $c$ large enough, then the resulting function will have no zeroes.  Note that it is important that the original polynomial has odd degree; otherwise, its antiderivative has odd degree and will always have at least one root.